# Date shows in incorrect language

Tags: indicator, settings, time

There are a little problem.
I had download Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my native lang, but, 'cause translation incomplete and inaccurate in some places, I switched to English (without reinstalled).
Mostly it was done, but Date in right upper corner (Unity) shows in my native lang, while I 'd prefer English.
Time'n'Date Settings doesn't contain preferred lang...
So, how I can handle with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open system and settings and select language support.Select the `Regional Formats` tab,from this tab select the date format you want(English) and then click `Apply-System-Wide`.
Logout and login for the changes to take effect.